# How to remove Chamilo footer Content

Tags: php, html, css

I will like to know how to remove the footer content ''Portal Chamilo 1.9.8 © 2014'' in Chamilo LMC. I have tried footer.tpl but it won't remove.

```
    <div id="software_name">
                {{ "Platform"|get_lang }} <a href="{{_p.web}}" target="_blank">{{_s.software_name}} {{_s.system_version}}</a>
                &copy; {{ "now"|date("Y") }}
            </div>
```

I removed the above code in the footer.tpl but nothing changed. Pls anyone that can help.

Comment: It's Chamilo LMS (not LMC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily change the name of the platform and the version from your /app/config/configuration.php file:

```
$_configuration['software_name']     = 'Chamilo';
$_configuration['software_url']      = 'http://www.chamilo.org/';
// Version settings
$_configuration['system_version']    = '1.9.8';
```

If you want to play with the templates, you should indeed change the files in main/templates/default/ (usually inside the layout/ folder there), but you *must* flush Twig's cache, which is located in archive/twig/
There is also a link on the administration page that says "Archive directory cleanup", and that will do it (between other safe cache clean-up things).

Comment: For versions 1.9.* and below, the configuration file is in main/inc/conf/configuration.php.
For version 1.10.0 and above, the configuration file is in app/config/configuration.php

Answer (score 1):

Chamilo is using [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) to parse templates. These templates are being compiled and saved in the  `your_installation_dir/archive/twig` directory. Did you clear that directory? If you have APC extension enabled, and clearing cache doesn't work, it might be also good idea to clear APC cache.